# Type checking an imported json file

Tags: json, typescript

Apologies if any of my terminology is incorrect, I have only recently started using TypeScript after too many years in pure JavaScript.

I have a Vue + TypeScript project (using Volar's Takeover mode). In this project are several .json files I'm importing as a data source. I have created Typescript interfaces or types for this data. These files have been imported correctly (i.e. my tsconfig contains the `"resolveJsonModule": true` flag), and for the most part work. For example, a JSON import containing something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "basic_attack",
    "name": "Attack",
    "cost": [
      {
        "attribute": "actionPoints",
        "operator": "-",
        "magnitude": 1
      }
    ],
    "validTargets": ["notSelf"],
    "effects": [
      {
        "target": "target",
        "type": "modifier",
        "modifier": {
          "attribute": "health",
          "operator": "+",
          "magnitude": 4
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  // etc
]
```

Is imported as follows:

```
import _skills from 'data/content/skills/basic.json';

interface ISkillDataModel {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  description?: string;
  cost: IAttributeModifier[];
  effects: TSkillEffectDataModel[];
  validTargets: ESkillTargetType[];
}
const skills = _skills as ISkillDataModel[];
```

(I've left the nested interfaces out of the question as I don't think they're directly relevant and would double its length)

However in one case I noticed one of the nested properties in my JSON structure was invalid but was not reporting an error according to the TypeScript engine. After some playing around I found that it would correctly report a type conversion error if the JSON file only contained a single entry.

From what I've been able to Google, when I assign the type to the raw JSON with my `_skills as ISkillDataModel[]` I am asserting to the TypeScript engine that it is of that type. If an array within this JSON file contains only a single object, it will still type check the properties, but if it contains multiple objects it will blindly believe the assertion. Is this correct?

Is there a way to get the TypeScript engine to type check the entire file, or do I need to try an alternative approach if I want the JSON file strictly validated? What might these approaches be? I've toyed with the idea of using JSONSchema validation, but that feels like a duplication of work given I already have TypeScript interfaces defined.